# Settings Autoack true in Rabbitmq and celery

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am using celery and rabbitmq , but due to pushing several task in queue my server memory  utilization becomes more than 40% , so that rabbit further will not accepting any task . so i want to delete those message which are already executed , but due to durable behavior of rabbitmq those message not automatically delete, so i want to set some configuration like autoAck=True , so that if message is consumed from celery ,it will delete from rabbitmq queues and also from my server memory. please explain how can we do that .

Comment: I voted to close, because you didn't provide enough information for us to help you. From the description you gave, messages are not being removed from the queue, but there are many reasons why this might be. Please provide details as to the code you are using.

Comment: 1.One of the reason for this issue that i will pushing more messages in the queue and rate of consuming message from queue is less...so that messages in queue is continuously increasing and Rabbitmq keep messages in memory , as memory usage increase rabbitmq not taking any further messages after vm_memory_high_watermark ..

Comment: 2. i just want to celery configration . so that once message is consumed by celery or consumer , that message automatically deleted from rabbitmq.

Comment: But what is your question? The behavior described I the default behavior.

Comment: want to know why memory utilization becomes increase day by day for rabbitmq.

Comment: If you never remove a message from the queue, then that's exactly what is going to happen. Why aren't you acknowledging the messages when you are done processing them?

Answer (score 5):

OK, so while I don't fully understand *why* you have the problem you have, it is clear what is going on.

1. A publisher puts a message task in the queue
2. Your worker process pulls the message and processes it
3. The message is never actually removed from the queue

This behavior happens when a consumer fails to acknowledge the processing of a message.  To confirm, if you look at the RabbitMQ management plug-in, you'll see a whole bunch of unacknowledged messages. These will be unavailable for consumption, but will continue to be held on the server and taking up disk space and memory.

Further, if you do a `Basic.Recover`, all of these messages will then get dumped back into the queue to be processed again.

This problem is due to incorrect configuration of your consumer. There are two ways to address this:

1. You can configure the consumer to auto-ack (i.e. acknowledge the message automatically upon receipt). This is done when you declare the consumer (using `Basic.Consume`).  **Edit**: It looks like this may be the [default behavior of Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.acks_late).
2. You can configure your worker process to submit an acknowledgement (using `Basic.Ack`). **Edit**: this is done via the [acks_late](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.acks_late) property in Celery.

Comment: Can u please tell us how i configure python Celery ( from consumer side) so that once message  is consumed , i will remove from queue.how i apply auto-ack true in celery.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use Celery. Perhaps search for "celery auto ack" or ask another question on SO so someone who knows can answer. Or maybe someone else can post another answer here.

Comment: please let me know how i process again unacknowledged message from rabbitmq.

Comment: Kill and restart the Celery process.